Django ModuleNotFoundError in Vercel production
I'm trying to deploy an api on vercel in Django, however when I call my api I get an error that a module does not exist. I don't get this error locally.

I've tried several solutions: adding a route to the folder in settings.py, installing modules with build_files.sh. I still have the same problem, even though the files are present in the aborescense of my production project.
Here is the link to my github repository: https://github.com/SkyBLUE62/osint_sherlock_api
vercel.json

{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "api/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/static/(.*)",
      "dest": "/static/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "api/wsgi.py"
    }
  ]
}

build_files.sh
echo "BUILD START"

# create a virtual environment named 'venv' if it doesn't already exist
python3.9 -m venv venv

# activate the virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate

# install all deps in the venv
pip install -r requirements.txt

# collect static files using the Python interpreter from venv
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
echo "BUILD END"

# [optional] Start the application here 
# python manage.py runserver

api/settings.py
"""
Django settings for api project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '%a#x#-ara^lpz(ljb7_%i!bahh7yyfjtbud*0%%sc0v($8hveh'
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'execution', 'sherlock'))

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.vercel.app']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'cli',
    'example',
    'execution'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.app'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'

# Cross-Origin

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}

api/wsgi.py
"""
WSGI config for api project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

app = get_wsgi_application()

Project Tree in Prod


requirements.txt
djangorestframework>=3.12.2
django-cors-headers>=3.6.0
sherlock-project==0.15.0
Config Postman or ThunderClient to call a api

